# What's the easiest way to create a fully-patched Ubuntu installer?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, usb-installation

I have two laptops on which I re-install Ubuntu (and derivatives) regularly. Both of them present hardware problems that make installation/testing more time consuming and bumpy: one of them has Nvidia problems (max res: 800x600; not so terrible when installing, but prevents me from comfortably testing a distro from live); the other has Broadcom problems (no wifi—more annoying, since ethernet is not readily available).

Since both of these problems are solved by installing all updates (and are not present in distros like Kali, meant to be run from live), I'm wondering what's the easiest way to create a fully-patched installation image/USB?

Comment: The standard ISO is intended to be run in live mode and do updates during installation. You can install it do another USB which means it allows updates itself when used allowing you to add apps. The 'install' script won't be copied to it (to my knowledge), but many install scripts exist for this purpose better suited.  At a place I volunteer we have a real system on hdd; which is cloned 15-40 times a week for 'new' systems; with only nvidia drivers added manually (by script) and fine-tuning for 'sound' and the rest is just testing. For two machines I'd just use normal install.

Comment: Well your "problem", IMHO, is that you are using hardware that is not Linux compatible due to the lack of open source drivers. Licensing issues prevent Canonical, and most distros, from distributing the drivers in their .iso. So you have to remaster the .iso to include the drivers you want / need . I don't think your "problem" has anything to do with the installer or installation scripts.

Comment: @guiverc: Is there any install script you would recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You can use systemback for creating fully patched installation image.

Steps to install systemback on ubuntu.

```
Sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback
Sudo apt-get update
Sudo apt-get install systemback
```

In this you can create a restore point also and iso file of your current installed system up to 4gb maximum size.
Then use this iso file for creating bootable USB stick.

Comment: Thanks, vipul! At the moment I'm already setup, but I'll accept when I get around to testing.